# Looking for a function that can detect the last (previous) wick or body that was within the range of the top or bottom wick of a candle)

Tags: pine-script

I want to add this to an indicator script that I am creating, and then plot it under certain conditions as a translucent box that leads from the top and bottom of either the top or bottom wick (one or the other depending on certain parameters) back to that point where there is a candle that interrupts the empty space in between. Any ideas?

Honestly totally lost here